# call_user_func_array not working on php 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I recently tried using an old code I wrote for PHP 5.3 on a project that's running on a server that runs PHP 5.6. Though my code runs on my local machine (windows - PHP 5.3), it shows the error below when i try to use on my online host:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in /home/lj7mxu21cx3y/public_html/crud/datamodel.php on line 54

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /home/lj7mxu21cx3y/public_html/crud/datamodel.php on line 55
```

this is my code below:

```
function useRecord($mysqli,$query_string="",$type="",$vars=[]){

$query = $mysqli->prepare($query_string);
// create an empty array
$parameters = array();
// push the type string into the array by reference
$parameters[] = & $type;
// push the items from $vars array into the array by reference
for ($i = 0; $i < count($vars); $i++) {
    $parameters[] = & $vars[$i];
}

// call mysqli_stmt::bind_param with the $parameters array, which contains [type, var1, var2, ...]
call_user_func_array(array($query, "bind_param"), $parameters);
$query->execute();
$result = null;
preg_match("/^[A-Z]+/", $query_string, $command);
switch ($command[0]) {
    case "SELECT":
        $result = $query->get_result();
        break;
    case "INSERT":
    case "UPDATE":
    case "DELETE":
        $result = $query->affected_rows;
        break;
}
$query->close();
return $result;



 }
```

i am using the mysql native driver for php -- **mysqlnd** on my WebHost (Godaddy). **EDIT:: Also, this function is used within a namespaced class**

Comment: Could you please run - var_dump($query); and show here.

Comment: And show how execute this function - useRecord

Comment: sorry for late response, the question was a little slow to get responses. $query returns a valid statement object, or at least much like this `object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) } object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["errno"]=> int(0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$query` is not an object you need to scroll up to its definition:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare($query_string);
```

Checking [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) we can see the function can return two data types (emphasis mine):

> `mysqli_prepare()` returns a statement object or **`FALSE` if an error occurred**.

Your code doesn't handle error conditions. You need to [at least detect them](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting):

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

---

A shorter test case ([demo](https://3v4l.org/itd98)):

```
call_user_func_array(array(false, 'whatever'), array());
```

Comment: $query returns a valid statement object

Comment: @Ndydaniel If that's the case, are you positively sure the code you've shared is exactly the code that exhibits the issue? Is there a chance you're calling the function more than once and only some calls fail? Can you edit the question and show the exact method you've used to determine that `$query` is a valid statement object?

Comment: failure to use this `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` cause the error message to be rather ambiguous. it help me locate a wayward column that wasn't defined on my db. thanks a lot